# Parse CSV file in C

Tags: c, parsing, csv

Is there a library I can use to parse CSV files in C. I am on a Linux system. I know about [this](http://code.google.com/p/csv-parser-cplusplus/) but it is in C++ and I need something in C. Don't want to go through the pain of debugging and testing if someone has already done it.

Comment: http://amath.colorado.edu/courses/management/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25429408/c-how-to-read-an-advanced-excel-like-csv-file

Comment: C CSV Parser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser/ C CSV Writer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvwriter/

Comment: The fastest CSV parser happens to be in C and is MIT licensed: https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [libcsv](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/), which is a CSV library written in ANSI C89.

Comment: Having trouble downloading the library. Will try it tomorrow.

Comment: libcsv is licensed under GPL, be careful.

Comment: @Mojtaba It is LGPL, so you can dynamically link libcsv to your application, proprietary or open source.

Comment: Copy on GitHub https://github.com/robertpostill/libcsv

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple CSV parser library that's described in the excellent book [The Practice of Programming](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/tpop.webpage/) by
[Kernighan and Pike](http://smile.amazon.com/dp/020161586X), and the source is available from the site linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing a CSV is no too much complicated, depend of the CSV structure, take a look at the  [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) function.

Comment: Parsing a CSV file with quotes and commas in the field values using `strtok()` is not particularly easy.

Comment: Are you right, in some cases with complex CSVs may require some work, I'll edit my post.

Comment: This is a very very bad idea.  strtok interprets ",," and "," the same. when comma is the seperator.  Your tokens can end up in the wrong columns.