# Rigorous definition for CSV file reading/writing

Tags: c, csv

I have written my own CSV reader/writer in C to store records in a character column in an ODBC database. Unfortunately I have discovered many edge cases that trip over my implementation, and I have come to the conclusion my problem is that I have not rigorously defined the rules for CSV. I've read RFC4180, but it seems incomplete and does not resolve ambiguities.

For example, should "" be considered an empty token or a double quote? Do quotes match outside-in or left to right? What do I do with an input string that has unmatched single quotes? The real mess begins when I have nested tokens, which doubles up the escaped quotation characters.

What I really need is a definitive CSV standard that I can implement in code. Every time I feel I have nailed every corner case, I find another one. I am sure this problem has been mulled over and solved many times over by superior minds to mine, has anyone written a rigorous definition of CSV that I can implement in code? I realise C is not the ideal language here, but I don't have a choice about the compiler at this stage; nor can I use a third party library (unless it compiles with C-90). Boost is not an option as my compiler doesn't support C++. I have contemplated ditching CSV for XML, but it seems like overkill for storing a few tokens in a 256 character database record. Anyone made a definitive CSV spec?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115529/parse-csv-file-in-c

The library suggested here is ANSI C89 compliant.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard (see Wikipedia's article, in particular http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard), so in order to use CSV, you need to follow the general principle of being conservative in what you generate and liberal in what you accept. In particular:

- Do not use quotation marks for blank fields. Simply write an empty field (two adjacent delimiters, or a delimiter in the first/last position of the line).
- Quote any field containing a quotation mark, comma, or newline.

Comment: While the RFC is not a standard, it is very clear - I see no confusion in the wording. The Wikipedia article you linked talks about CSV files in layman terms - for example, Excel groups all text-based files under CSV and then the import wizard can be used to select the separator, etc.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's very good advice to have different rules for quoting field values when writing a CSV file. If all field values are quoted, parsing the file is a very simple matter.

Comment: @xxbbcc: As OP noted, quoting blank fields is not "being conservative in what you generate" because there's an ambiguity as to how `""` is interpreted. Even the RFC is unclear unless you just ignore the English text of the RFC and follow the ABNF grammar.

Comment: Why do you say there's ambiguity in the RFC? Maybe you're right but I don't see why. Page 2 of the RFC clearly states how to read a field value. Do you have an example of a valid field value that cannot be parsed?

Comment: An example of the complexity I'm seeing is when you have an input string like: 
 "5,5"" pipe","6"" pipe"
Clearly the way you interpret this string depends entirely on what order you apply the rules. For example, since it starts and ends with a quote, is the entire string literal? Or do I swap out double-quotes for single-quotes first, then interpret the single quotes as qualifiers and read the first token as:
 5,5" pipe

Comment: @Piers `"5,5"" pipe"` is one string literal. You cannot use tokenizing functions to read this data - you must parse it from left to right and when you do, it's clear how to read it. `"5,5"" pipe","6"" pipe"` represents 2 field values. The comma in `5,5` is not a field separator because by the time you reach the comma character, you're already inside a quoted field - there's no need to swap out the double quotes. Why do you say this is complex? I must be missing something here - read my answer below, it has all the rules (from the RFC, really).

Comment: @xxbbcc - you are saying it is not complex, yet you just declared a bunch of rules to apply in a certain order: first ignore "" as an empty string (or not), then look for leading quote, then substitute 2 double-quotes, then match ending unescaped quote. Change the order of these and the interpretation and resulting string is different. The RFC does not specify the order of applying these rules when reading/writing CSV (nor the ambiguity of how to interpret ""), which is what I mean by not being "rigorously defined". Not sure what you mean by not tokenising either, did you mean no strtok() ?

Comment: @Piers I think you misunderstand how a record (and a field) is supposed to be processed. I didn't make up any rules - I simply translated the rules from the RFC. The way you need to process a single record in CSV is by parsing character by character, from left to right. This can be done using a very simple state machine - it's a trivial task. You _cannot_, however, use functions like `strtok()` or `split()`, regex or variants of these. I really don't see how the RFC could be clearer. Let me know if you want to chat - I don't want to hijack @R..'s answer (any more :) ).

Comment: @Piers Chat link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/31366/csv-record-parsing?tab=general

I'll be here for a while if you want to chat real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Find the most authoritative CSV library you trust and read the source.  CSV is not so complicated that you won't be able to understand its rules from a comprehensive reading of a source implementation.  I have been happy with Java's [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).  Perl's is [here](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm), and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2), fields should be parsed from left to right to correctly interpret a double quote. In some contexts `""` is an escaped double quote (when inside a quoted field), otherwise it's either an empty string or two double quotes (when inside an otherwise non-empty field value).

For example, consider a file with 4 records (1 column):

```
"field""value" CRLF
"" CRLF
field""value CRLF
"field value" extra CRLF
```

1. `"field""value"` - should be read as `field"value`
2. `""` - should be read as an empty string
3. `field""value` - should be read as `field""value`
4. `"field value" extra` - could be read as `field value extra` or you can reject it

Record 4 is really an invalid field so you can either accept it or reject it.

When you start reading a field, you need to check if the first character read is a double quote or not. If the first character is a double quote, the field value is quoted and you need to read until you find an unescaped closing double quote. In this case you can ignore new lines and comma characters, since the field is quoted - it only ends when you encouter a closing double quote.

If the first character is not a double quote then all double quotes in the field value should be treated as literal double qoutes. In this case you reach the end of the field when you encounter a comma or a new line character.

Based on this, I'd recommend to always quote all fields when you write out records and write a proper parser to parse records when you read data. This way you can store any data in your CSV files (even multiline text with embedded quotes) and your format will be clear. When reading a CSV file, I'd fail all files that cannot be correctly parsed - if this is a database, you can expect users to not to mess with the records manually, unless they know what they're doing.