# C Reading multiple structs from text

Tags: c, struct

Hey I have been trying to read multiple structs from a text file and count how many structs have been read in my project.

this is my struct:

```
#define Input_Length_fileName 25 /*maximum letter for Input*/ 
#define Input_Length_description 80 /*maximum letter for Input*/ 
#define DataSize 200 /*maximum letter for one pic*/ 
#define Maximun_Picture 20 /*maximum photos in recoude*/

typedef struct picture_Data
{
char fileName[Input_Length_fileName];
char description[Input_Length_description];
char location[Input_Length_fileName];
int peopleCount;
}pic;
```

this is the reading structs function:

```
#define PIC_FILE "Pic.dat"
int readFile (pic *entries, int pic_order){

FILE * infile;
int count = 0;
char line[DataSize];

infile = fopen(PIC_FILE, "rb");

if (infile != NULL)
{
    count = fread(entries, sizeof(pic), Maximun_Picture, infile);

    while (fgets(line, DataSize, infile)!=NULL)
    {

        sscanf(line, "%s,%s,%s,%d", &entries[pic_order].fileName, &entries[pic_order].description, &entries[pic_order].location, &entries[pic_order].peopleCount);              
    }

    fclose(infile);
}
entries[count].fileName[0]= '\0';

return count;
}
```

this is how the text file

```
 photo1,I love this photo1,Helsinki,20
 photo2,I love this photo2,Pari,30
```

this is how I call it

```
for ( i = 0; i < Maximun_Picture; i++)
  {
     pic_recorded_number = readFile(&picture_record[i],i);
  }


    printf("%d\n", pic_recorded_number);
    printf("%d\n", picture_record[0].peopleCount);
```

I know it is not right. Can somebody tell me what s wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you very mych!!

Comment: Don't do `while (!feof(...))`, it will not work as you expect. The reason being that the `EOF` flag is not set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file, so you end up iterating the loop once too many. Instead do e.g. `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`

Comment: @gargankit typing mistake, sorry

Comment: There's also some confusion if you have a binary file or a text file? If you have a binary file then use `fread` in a loop, if you have a text file you do `fgets` in a loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: A lot of bad tutorials online.. hopefully saying that enough will keep people from doing it

Comment: Alos, your `sscanf` format doesn't match the input, and can never work unless you have some whitespace between the fields in the file.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Trying it but seems still not right. Thanks anyway

Comment: In this sentence: `photo1,I love this photo1,Helsinki,20`, you cannot use `sscanf` to get description as `I love this photo1`, instead it would be just `love` because of the issues `scanf` family of functions face with `white-spaces`. You should try `strtok` on `,` delimitter to get correct strings

Comment: For scanning `char` arrays like filename, description and location. you do not need `&` before them, while pasing to `sscanf`

Comment: @Thanks but i define the file name in the header

Comment: Policy is not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define Input_Length_fileName 25 /*maximum letter for Input*/ 
#define Input_Length_description 80 /*maximum letter for Input*/ 
#define DataSize 200 /*maximum letter for one pic*/ 
#define Maximun_Picture 20 /*maximum photos in recoude*/

typedef struct picture_Data{
    char fileName[Input_Length_fileName];
    char description[Input_Length_description];
    char location[Input_Length_fileName];
    int peopleCount;
} pic;

#define PIC_FILE "Pic.dat"

int readFile (pic *entries){//[, int pic_order] : Not required If you are reading all.
    FILE * infile;
    int count = 0;
    char line[DataSize];

    if(NULL == (infile = fopen(PIC_FILE, "r")))// "r" : text file
        return 0;
    //count = fread(entries, sizeof(pic), Maximun_Picture, infile);//for fwrite

    while (fgets(line, DataSize, infile)!=NULL){
        sscanf(line, " %[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d",
        entries[count].fileName, entries[count].description, entries[count].location, &entries[count].peopleCount);
        if(++count >= Maximun_Picture)
            break;
    }
    fclose(infile);
    return count;
}

int main(){
    pic picture_record[Maximun_Picture];
    int pic_recorded_number = readFile(picture_record);

    printf("%d\n", pic_recorded_number);
    printf("%s\n", picture_record[0].description);
    printf("%d\n", picture_record[0].peopleCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I (almost) wish *scanf functions were never invented.

This will easily break; consider a `,` in the description (or any of the string fields).

Make life easy on yourself and don't reinvent the wheel: use a library that implements a common data interface, such as CSV.

(Granted, in C there are none in the standard library).

Take at look at this SO question: [Parse CSV file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115529/parse-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: I am not allowed to used any non-standard library... Thanks anyway