# C: How to read an advanced, Excel like, CSV file?

Tags: c, csv

I am looking for a C library that can properly parse CSV files in Excel format, such as there in other common languages, such as **Python** and **Java**

For instance, the following text is a record in Excel format:

```
hello,world,"This is one field, really, no joking",12345,,,
```

Here is another example with **a single multiline field** (Fully supported in Excel):

```
hello,world,"This multiline text
is considered as one field

that ends here",and,these,are,other,fields,at,the,same,row
```

Comment: I wrote `Excel`, but it is true also for `OpeenOffice Calc`. I prefer something that works in all platforms

Comment: Ok, it's C and not C++, I've changed the subject and the tagging. It has value in C, as I didn't find anything similar in the web. It's not a duplicate thread...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally wrote API by myself, after not finding a satisfying answer in the web

Sharing...

**Usage Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "csvparser.h"

int main() {
    int i =  0;
    //                                   file, delimiter, first_line_is_header?
    CsvParser *csvparser = CsvParser_new("Book1.csv", ",", 1);
    CsvRow *header;
    CsvRow *row;

    header = CsvParser_getHeader(csvparser);
    if (header == NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", CsvParser_getErrorMessage(csvparser));
        return 1;
    }
    char **headerFields = CsvParser_getFields(header);
    for (i = 0 ; i < CsvParser_getNumFields(header) ; i++) {
        printf("TITLE: %s\n", headerFields[i]);
    }
    while ((row = CsvParser_getRow(csvparser)) ) {
        char **rowFields = CsvParser_getFields(row);
        for (i = 0 ; i < CsvParser_getNumFields(row) ; i++) {
            printf("FIELD: %s\n", rowFields[i]);
        }
        CsvParser_destroy_row(row);
    }
    CsvParser_destroy(csvparser);
    return 0;
}
```

**Header file - csvparser.h**:

```
#ifndef CSVPARSER_H
#define CSVPARSER_H

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct CsvRow {
    char **fields_;
    int numOfFields_;
} CsvRow;

typedef struct CsvParser {
    char *filePath_;
    char delimiter_;
    int firstLineIsHeader_;
    char *errMsg_;
    CsvRow *header_;
    FILE *fileHandler_;
} CsvParser;


// Public
CsvParser *CsvParser_new(const char *filePath, const char *delimiter, int firstLineIsHeader);
void CsvParser_destroy(CsvParser *csvParser);
void CsvParser_destroy_row(CsvRow *csvRow);
CsvRow *CsvParser_getHeader(CsvParser *csvParser);
CsvRow *CsvParser_getRow(CsvParser *csvParser);
int CsvParser_getNumFields(CsvRow *csvRow);
char **CsvParser_getFields(CsvRow *csvRow);
const char* CsvParser_getErrorMessage(CsvParser *csvParser);
int CsvParser_getNumOfFields(const CsvRow *csvRow);

// Private
CsvRow *_CsvParser_getRow(CsvParser *csvParser);    
int _CsvParser_delimiterIsAccepted(const char *delimiter);
void _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(CsvParser *csvParser, const char *errorMessage);


#endif
```

**Implementation - csvparser.c**:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "csvparser.h"

CsvParser *CsvParser_new(const char *filePath, const char *delimiter, int firstLineIsHeader) {
    CsvParser *csvParser = malloc(sizeof(CsvParser));
    if (filePath == NULL) {
        csvParser->filePath_ = NULL;
    } else {
        int filePathLen = strlen(filePath);
        csvParser->filePath_ = malloc((filePathLen + 1));
        strcpy(csvParser->filePath_, filePath);
    }
    csvParser->firstLineIsHeader_ = firstLineIsHeader;
    csvParser->errMsg_ = NULL;
    if (delimiter == NULL) {
        csvParser->delimiter_ = ',';
    } else if (_CsvParser_delimiterIsAccepted(delimiter)) {
        csvParser->delimiter_ = *delimiter;
    } else {
        csvParser->delimiter_ = '\0';
    }
    csvParser->header_ = NULL;
    csvParser->fileHandler_ = NULL;

    return csvParser;
}

void CsvParser_destroy(CsvParser *csvParser) {
    if (csvParser == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if (csvParser->filePath_ != NULL) {
        free(csvParser->filePath_);
    }
    if (csvParser->errMsg_ != NULL) {
        free(csvParser->errMsg_);
    }
    if (csvParser->fileHandler_ != NULL) {
        fclose(csvParser->fileHandler_);
    }
    if (csvParser->header_ != NULL) {
        CsvParser_destroy_row(csvParser->header_);
    }
    free(csvParser);
}

void CsvParser_destroy_row(CsvRow *csvRow) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i < csvRow->numOfFields_ ; i++) {
        free(csvRow->fields_[i]);
    }
    free(csvRow);
}

CsvRow *CsvParser_getHeader(CsvParser *csvParser) {
    if (! csvParser->firstLineIsHeader_) {
        _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(csvParser, "Cannot supply header, as current CsvParser object does not support header");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (csvParser->header_ == NULL) {
        csvParser->header_ = _CsvParser_getRow(csvParser);
    }
    return csvParser->header_;
}

CsvRow *CsvParser_getRow(CsvParser *csvParser) {
    if (csvParser->firstLineIsHeader_ && csvParser->header_ == NULL) {
        csvParser->header_ = _CsvParser_getRow(csvParser);
    }
    return _CsvParser_getRow(csvParser);
}

int CsvParser_getNumFields(CsvRow *csvRow) {
    return csvRow->numOfFields_;
}

char **CsvParser_getFields(CsvRow *csvRow) {
    return csvRow->fields_;
}

CsvRow *_CsvParser_getRow(CsvParser *csvParser) {
    int accceptedFields = 64;
    int acceptedCharsInField = 64;
    if (csvParser->filePath_ == NULL) {
        _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(csvParser, "Supplied CSV file path is NULL");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (csvParser->delimiter_ == '\0') {
        _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(csvParser, "Supplied delimiter is not supported");
        return NULL;
    }
    if (csvParser->fileHandler_ == NULL) {
        csvParser->fileHandler_ = fopen(csvParser->filePath_, "r");
        if (csvParser->fileHandler_ == NULL) {
            int errorNum = errno;
            const char *errStr = strerror(errorNum);
            char *errMsg = malloc(1024 + strlen(errStr));
            strcpy(errMsg, "");
            sprintf(errMsg, "Error opening CSV file for reading: %s : %s", csvParser->filePath_, errStr);
            _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(csvParser, errMsg);
            free(errMsg);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    CsvRow *csvRow = malloc(sizeof(CsvRow));
    csvRow->fields_ = malloc(accceptedFields * sizeof(char*));
    csvRow->numOfFields_ = 0;
    int fieldIter = 0;
    char *currField = malloc(acceptedCharsInField);
    int inside_complex_field = 0;
    int currFieldCharIter = 0;
    int seriesOfQuotesLength = 0;
    int lastCharIsQuote = 0;
    int isEndOfFile = 0;
    while (1) {
        char currChar = fgetc(csvParser->fileHandler_);
        if (feof(csvParser->fileHandler_)) {
            if (currFieldCharIter == 0 && fieldIter == 0) {
                _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(csvParser, "Reached EOF");
                return NULL;
            }
            currChar = '\n';
            isEndOfFile = 1;
        }
        if (currChar == '\r') {
            continue;
        }
        if (currFieldCharIter == 0  && ! lastCharIsQuote) {
            if (currChar == '\"') {
                inside_complex_field = 1;
                lastCharIsQuote = 1;
                continue;
            }
        } else if (currChar == '\"') {
            seriesOfQuotesLength++;
            inside_complex_field = (seriesOfQuotesLength % 2 == 0);
            if (inside_complex_field) {
                currFieldCharIter--;
            }
        } else {
            seriesOfQuotesLength = 0;
        }
        if (isEndOfFile || ((currChar == csvParser->delimiter_ || currChar == '\n') && ! inside_complex_field)) {
            currField[lastCharIsQuote ? currFieldCharIter - 1 : currFieldCharIter] = '\0';
            csvRow->fields_[fieldIter] = malloc(currFieldCharIter + 1);
            strcpy(csvRow->fields_[fieldIter], currField);
            free(currField);
            csvRow->numOfFields_++;
            if (currChar == '\n') {
                return csvRow;
            }
            acceptedCharsInField = 64;
            currField = malloc(acceptedCharsInField);
            currFieldCharIter = 0;
            fieldIter++;
            inside_complex_field = 0;
        } else {
            currField[currFieldCharIter] = currChar;
            currFieldCharIter++;
            if (currFieldCharIter == acceptedCharsInField - 1) {
                acceptedCharsInField *= 2;
                currField = realloc(currField, acceptedCharsInField);
            }
        }
        lastCharIsQuote = (currChar == '\"') ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

int CsvParser_getNumOfFields(const CsvRow *csvRow) {
    return csvRow->numOfFields_;
}

int _CsvParser_delimiterIsAccepted(const char *delimiter) {
    char actualDelimiter = *delimiter;
    if (actualDelimiter == '\n' || actualDelimiter == '\r' || actualDelimiter == '\0' ||
            actualDelimiter == '\"') {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void _CsvParser_setErrorMessage(CsvParser *csvParser, const char *errorMessage) {
    if (csvParser->errMsg_ != NULL) {
        free(csvParser->errMsg_);
    }
    int errMsgLen = strlen(errorMessage);
    csvParser->errMsg_ = malloc(errMsgLen + 1);
    strcpy(csvParser->errMsg_, errorMessage);
}

const char *CsvParser_getErrorMessage(CsvParser *csvParser) {
    return csvParser->errMsg_;
}
```

Comment: No. In case that it exceeds 64, it becomes 128. If exceeds 128, it becomes 256, and so on...

Comment: Overall functionality looks good & complete.  Number of minor nits that a posting of this code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com may reveal.  +1

Comment: @MatthieuM. I've just looked at the link - and ensured that my parser works exactly as written there. I've tested my code with very hard-to-parse excel files, with examples as I showed above in the question body

Comment: You're welcome! I published it in sourceforge, you can visit the site from time to time, there may be updates along the time: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser/ . Check the Wiki page for documentation