# Is there another way to split a string with a comma delimiter aside from strtok?

Tags: c

I'm reading a CSV file and I'd like to split each line into multiple different variables. I've about strtok, some people recommend it, others say it's problematic. So is there another method of splitting my strings?

Comment: What do you mean by "better".

Comment: @ErikGodard By better, I mean something more widely accepted. As I mentioned, some people don't recommend strtok, so I'm looking for something "safer".

Comment: Use a third-party library. Take a look at the answers to this question for a couple recommendations: [Parse a CSV file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115529/parse-csv-file-in-c)

Comment: If we drop the *better*, and just go with *another method*, I wrote two very simple C functions [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/165812-researching-how-best-import-csv-separate-content-2.html#post1223835): `csv_field()` and `csv_next()`. The first one is like `fgets()`, except it only reads one field; the second moves to the next record. For real use, I'd add dynamic memory allocation, thus changing the interface to `csv_field(char **, size_t *, FILE *)` and `csv_next(FILE *)`, but it's only maybe a dozen or two lines more.

Answer (score 2):

To parse CSV source lines, you must handle the syntax for `"` delimited strings that can embed `,` characters. You cannot use `strtok()` directly.  Furthermore, `strtok()` considers sequences of delimiters to be equivalent to a single delimiter, which is definitely not what you want for the `,` delimiter.

I'm afraid you must write a parser *by hand*, iterating through the CSV lines, preferably read into a large buffer, and using some sort of state machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can `strchr` the delimeter in a loop and do something with each segment.

E.g., this'll split arguments on commas and print each field:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    for(int i = 1; i<argc; i++){
        char const *p0,*p1;
        for(p0=argv[i]; (p1=strchr(p0,',')); p0=p1+1 ){
            fwrite(p0,p1-p0,1,stdout); puts("");
        }
        fwrite(p0,strlen(p0),1,stdout); puts("");
    }
}
```

It's fairly straightforward.

Comment: `strchr()` is *better* than `strtok()`, but you still cannot handle `"` delimited strings with this function

Comment: @chqrlie Sure, and you answered that well. I generally just try to answer the gist of questions instead of trying to find out what the OP really needs. I personally think it's better for the site.