# How can i read a csv file in C?

Tags: c, csv

I need to reed a csv file in C.
I made a struct like this:

```
typedef struct Node{
  void** elem;
  List* next;
}List;
```

If I dont'know what's in csv file, how can I read the elements? They can be different in the same record.
A sample of a record is this:
12,ciao,45,2.4
Where i have a different type in the same record.
I saw fget function yet, but it return a char* or char... I would like something more generic because I don't know what there's in the record. 
I will use this struct with sorting algorithm.
In sorting algorithm i have a compare function like this

```
typedef int (*CompareFunction)(void*, void*);`
```

so if i can read void* on csv file and than put the element on the struct this wuold make easy the compare function.

Comment: Too broad as stated. Show us your efforts, we will try to help you on problems...

Comment: [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911299/read-csv-file-in-c) can give you a hand.

Comment: What are you going to do with your structure?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse CSV file in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115529/parse-csv-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a lot of function

[read function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)

[fgets function as you said](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

of course you don't know the content of your file but using a char * is the best solution

in both cases you will use a char * because it's the best way to read your file; and can convert your data to an other type really easily

for example if you read a number in your file, then you can convert it to an integer using [atoi](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atoi.3.html) for example

Comment: Ok, thank's! I was hoping there was a function like fget it couldn't returns me a char* but a generic void*.

Comment: then you can use read which takes a void * as buffer
but it's, i think easiest, to use a simple char *
depend of what you want to do then
@EnricoArnaudo

Comment: I would like to read the elements in csv, insert elements in the struct and then using sorting algorithm to ordered the struct.

Comment: In the sort algorithm my compare function is:                                                  typedef int (CompareFunction)(void, void); the function and the elem are pointer

Comment: The read() functions returns the number of byte read, how can i use this in my case?

Comment: @EnricoArnaudo it takes a pointer as second parameter, it's your buffer; read will write the data in this buffer

Comment: Ok, i see now an example, I understood what buffer return. It took me a while but I understood.

Comment: But if I don't know the size of my file, what can I put on count? Insert an approximate number is not a good solution

Comment: Is there any function in C that determin the size of a file?