# String into Array- efficient way

Tags: arrays, c, string

Given a string : `"A,B,C\n1,2,3\n,4,9,6"` how can I convert it into this 2D array (in C)?

```
[A B C
 1 2 3 
 4 9 6]
```

I thought to count the number of rows (by checking how many `\n`s there are +1) then count number of columns (by checking how many `','` there are +1) then, to allocate the 2D array. And then to put the values into the array.

Is there any way to do it in more efficient way? because I'm going through the same string many times.

Comment: Are all rows of the matrix guaranteed to be the same length?

Comment: 2 pass is safe and easy - pass (1) checks rows are all the same length (fixed number of columns) and counts the number of rows needed. Pass (2) populates the 2D-array using the above information.

Comment: Yes, all the rows are the same length @Botje. Thanks

Comment: You might find the `strtok` function (or `strtok_r`if available) useful.

Comment: It looks like CSV file. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/14115529/4989451

Comment: [C++] Using  `std::vector< std::vector<char> >` you can do this in one pass throwing an exception if rows are of unequal length.

Comment: @RichardCritten from the text (_"...into this 2D array (in C):"_) he apparently wants C.

Comment: To react on @RichardCritten comment about vectors, you can also use a dynamic array of pointers in C if you want a single pass action (through `realloc`, which is what a C++ vector uses under the hood).

Comment: @Jabberwocky there has been an edit [c++] tag removed and C/C++ changed to C - I was here before the changes :) Will leave my comments for now but may remove later.